# Facebook Oauth Issue | Multiple redirect with changing "code" parameter value in redirected url

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api

We are integrating our Silverlight based Desktop Application ( which talks to Servlet based backend solution ) with Facebook login. We are able to redirect to Facebook login page using below url

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=<client id>&redirect_uri=http://localhost.example.com/fbsignin&scope=email
```

But the issue here is that somehow Facebook is redirecting  Infinite/multiple times (with different-2 code value ) to our redirect url.

I checked on internet for same, and I think it is kind of known problem but all solutions provided only ask about updating PHP files or it SDK, but I am working on Servlet based bacend solution and not able to find any suitable solution to stop this multiple redirect.

Any Suggestion?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think I had a similar issue.

When you get a request with the 'code' parameter, then you will want to send that back to FB. Doing so will allow you to get an 'access_token' in return.

Relevant documentation can be read at this link: [Login Flow](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web-no-jssdk/#confirm)

And for clarity you would want to exchange the 'code' parameter for and 'access_token' by this GET request.

```
GET https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
    client_id={app-id}
   &redirect_uri={redirect-uri}
   &client_secret={app-secret}
   &code={code-parameter}
```

In general, your question is similar to this question:
[Get Facebook OAuth token from code parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237534/get-facebook-oauth-token-from-code-parameter)